# Correct time to save data in database when making resume maker website

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, react-hooks

Currently I am making a resume maker website with React, nodejs and MongoDB, I want to know when its a good idea to save data in database

1. Whenever user enters anything in database (that is `handleOnChange()`)
2. Other ?

Can anyone explain to me when and how if possible?

Currently I didn't try anything on backend, just finished the frontend part and want to know ideas before moving forward

Comment: You typically won't want to save on every possible change because that will save an incomplete state and it will result in a large number of database operations.  You can look at the typical auto-save settings in something like Microsoft Word for examples.  You would typically keep a flag for when anything has been edited and then auto-save when there is a pause in activity (e.g. not actively typing) and when it's been at least a few minutes since the prior save.  Once you auto-save, you clear the flag that marks it as edited.  You can play with the timer for how long between saves.

Comment: thanks a lot. This knowledge will come in handy.. I will be able to move forward now.Thankyou